# Play framework 2.4 (Java) mongo async db driver 3.0 query

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, playframework

Hello I'm trying to write async code for MongoDB async driver (3.0) http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/ with Play Framework 2.4 (Java) in controller with Async result https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync , when I'm testing it the Promise results is outside the Async call to MongoDB so sometimes I have empty json in the response, please can you help me with it ?

```
public F.Promise<Result> list() {
    final List<Document> accounts = new ArrayList<Document>();
    F.Promise<List<Document>> promiseOfAccounts = F.Promise.promise(
        new F.Function0<List<Document>>() {
            public List<Document> apply() {
                accountRepository.getCollection().find().into(accounts,
                        new SingleResultCallback<List<Document>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(final List<Document> result, final Throwable t) {
                            }
                        });
                return accounts;
            }
        }
    );
    return promiseOfAccounts.map(
        new F.Function<List<Document>, Result>() {
            public Result apply(List<Document> i) {
                return ok(i);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return `accounts`, the SigleResultCallback closure hasn't been executed. That results in the list being empty when the it's serialized in the `ok(i)` expression. To make it work, you have to resolve the promise yourself inside the `SingleResultCallback`. Remember Play `Promises` sit over scala `Future`s and scala Promises (which are different from Play `F.Promise`s). This is how you'd do it:

```
Promise<List<Document>> accountsPromise = Promise$.MODULE$.apply();
ArrayList<Document> accounts = new ArrayList<Document>();
accountRepository.getCollection().find().into(accounts,
        new SingleResultCallback<List<Document>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final List<Document> result, final Throwable t) {
                accountsPromise.success(result);
            }
        });
promiseOfAccounts=F.Promise.wrap(accountsPromise.future());
return promiseOfAccounts.map(
        new F.Function<List<Document>, Result>() {
            public Result apply(List<Document> i) {
                return ok(i);
            }
        }
);
```

the moment you call the `success` method of the scala `Promise` resolves, and so the value of the future becomes available, but you return the play `F.Promise` before that happens, the awesomeness of the reactive programming.